# Nuget cli with Nexus 3 OSS always getting 404

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to download Nuget packages through Nexus 3 OSS Nuget proxy repository that I just created.
Nexus: OSS 3.30.1-01
NuGet Version: 5.8.1.7021
I created Nuget proxy repository:
http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/
source for this repository is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

When running Nuget cli through Nexus:
C:\Nexus>nuget install jquery -source http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/
Feeds used:
http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/

Installing package 'jquery' to 'C:\Nexus'.
GET [http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/FindPackagesById()?id='jquery'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/FindPackagesById()?id=%27jquery%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0)
OK [http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/FindPackagesById()?id='jquery'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/FindPackagesById()?id=%27jquery%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0) 1138ms
Unable to find package 'jquery'

When running direct against official Nuget repository:
C:\Nexus>nuget install jquery -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Feeds used:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installing package 'jquery' to 'C:\Nexus'.
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/jquery/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/jquery/index.json 519ms
Package "jquery.3.6.0" is already installed.

I already tried to switch to Nuget v2 protocol. The result was pretty similar.
What I am missing?
Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Request should be: C:\Nexus>nuget install jquery -source http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/nuget-prx/index.json